# Creating Pixel texture

Tags: texturing, uv, export, uv-image-editor, pixel-art

I want to create pixel texture in pixel art software(aseprite) for my blender model, is it possible I export uv map and create pixel art from it and then import my pixel texture to blender?

I'm new to modeling
Thank you

Comment: in the UV Editor, you can export the UV: UV > Export UV Layout. You can also prepare a rough draft image and Image > Save As

Comment: Thank you for your answer